# Expected number of dice rolls to get $1$ OR $2$ 6's.

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a fair $6$ sided die. Let $A$ be the event that we roll a $1$ and $B$ be the event that we roll $2$ 6's in a row.

Now consider $X$ as random variable that takes value $n$ if $A$ OR $B$ happen after exactly $n$ rolls.

What is $E[X]$?

I know that individually, $E[X_A]=6$ and $E[X_B]=42$, where $X_A,X_B$ are the RVs which take value $n$ if it takes exactly $n$ rolls to achieve event $A,B$ respectively, but I'm not sure how to handle the case where we stop after $A$ OR $B$ happens.

For exmaple, $P(X=1)=1/6$ as the only possibility to stop is if we roll a 1, which occurs with probability $1/6$.

Similarly, $$P(x=2)=(5/6)(1/6)+(1/6)(1/6)$$
where the first term takes into account rolling something of the form $[\neq 1], 1$ (ie anything but 1, and then 1), and the second term is the probability of rolling $6,6$.

After this, things become hairy, since we want to consider
$[\neq 1,6],6,6$ OR $6,[\neq 1,6], 1$

and so on.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the expected number of subsequent rolls if the last die roll was **not** a $1$ or a $6$, and let $S$ be the number of expected subsequent rolls if the last die roll **was** a $6$. Note that the first case includes the starting roll, so $N$ is the answer we're looking for.

If your last die roll was not a $6$, there are three possibilities: (i) if you roll a $1$, you stop; (ii) if you roll a $6$, your expected number of further rolls is $S$; and (iii) if you roll any other number, your expected number of further rolls is $N$. This yields the equation

$$N = \frac{1}{6} (1) + \frac{1}{6} (S+1) + \frac{2}{3} (N+1)$$

If your last die roll was a $6$, there are two possibilities: (a) if you roll a $1$ or a $6$, you stop; and (b) if you roll any other number, your expected number of further rolls is again $N$. This yields the equation

$$S = \frac{1}{3} (1) + \frac{1}{3} (N+1)$$

Simplifying these two equations gives us the system

$$\begin{align}
2N &= S + 6 \\
3S &= 2N + 3
\end{align}$$

from which we get the answer $\boxed{N = \frac{21}{4}}$.

Comment: +1.  Alternatively say you might (a) roll a 1; (b) roll a 2,3,4,5 and start again ; (c) roll a 6 followed by a 1 or 6; or (d) roll a 6 followed by a 2,3,4,5 and start again.  So 
$N = \frac16 \times 1+ \frac46 \times(1+N) +\frac2{36}\times 2 + \frac4{36}\times (2+N)$   giving the same result

Comment: Yes, I actually double-checked my answer this way. Wasn't sure which one would be better to post; I went with the other way because I thought it might be slightly more versatile, though I don't know whether that's actually true.

Comment: @A.J. This is a great solution! I wouldn't have thought to look at it this way. Does this sort of reasoning have a more general name that I could look up?

Comment: It is a pretty common method to solve these kinds of questions, but I'm sorry, I don't know whether it has a name per se; it is related to an idea called 'states', so maybe looking for states-based solutions might be a start.